# Making symbolic functions without hard-coding in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to make symbolic functions `theta1(t)`, `theta2(t)`, `theta3(t)`,...,`thetaN(t)` where `N` is some parameter I can define in MATLAB. I know that I can use something like `sym('theta',[1 N])` to get `[theta1, theta2, theta3,..., thetaN]`. However, how can I do the same thing with theta being a function of t? The way to hard-code it would be like `syms theta1(t) theta2(t) theta3(t) ... thetaN(t)`, but I want to make this general.

I do not want to directly use the sym command here because "support of character vectors that are not valid variable names and do not define a number will be removed in a future release", meaning something like `sym('theta1(t)')` would not be valid in future releases.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured part of it out. I could do something like the following

```
for i = 1:N
    syms(strcat('theta',num2str(i),'(t)'))
end
```

However, if I want to assign a variable that contains all the symbolic expressions I'm still stuck. If I try

```
for i = 1:N
    my_array(i) = syms(strcat('theta',num2str(i),'(t)'))
end
```

I get `Error using syms (line 133). Using input and output arguments simultaneously is not supported.` It works if I use `sym` instead of `syms`, but this leads to the warning I mentioned in my original post.